# NHibernate QueryOver where ID is in a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, queryover

I have a webpage with criteria fields which filters data. The query for this is:

```
        CompanyAddress ca = null;
        CompanyAddress cad = null;
        WorkInfo wi = null;
        PrivateInfo pi = null;
        SearchResultInfo sri = null;

        /***************************/
        /* SEARCH FOR MAIN COMPANY */
        /***************************/

        var company = Session.QueryOver<Company>()
            .JoinAlias(c => c.Addresses, () => ca)
            .Where(() => ca.Main)
            .Where(c => c.Status == ContactStatus.Approved)
            .Select(
                Projections.Property("Id").WithAlias(() => sri.TopId),
                Projections.Property("ca.Id").WithAlias(() => sri.Id),
                Projections.Property("Name").WithAlias(() => sri.Name),
                Projections.Property("ca.Address").WithAlias(() => sri.Address),
                Projections.Property("ca.ContactData").WithAlias(() => sri.ContactData),
                Projections.Constant(ContactClassType.Company).WithAlias(() => sri.Type)
            );

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name)) company = company.WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.Name).IsLike("%" + _name + "%");

        //// TODO: fix error    
        if (_selectedTag != null) company = company.Where(Restrictions.In("_selectedTag", ca.Tags.Select(x => x.Tag.Id).ToArray()));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedCity)) company = company.Where(() => ca.Address.City == _selectedCity);          

        if (_selectedCountry != null) company = company.Where(() => ca.Address.Country.Id == _selectedCountry);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedZipCode)) company = company.Where(() => ca.Address.ZipCode == _selectedZipCode);          

        company.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<SearchResultInfo>());
```

Now if selectedTag has an ID the query gives me an error telling ca is null. All the other where clauses work except this one. So I want to check if the incoming ID is in the Tag list from the object CompanyAddress.

Does anyone have an idea whats wrong here?

**** SQL FROM ANDREW WITHTAKERS SOLUTION ****

```
SELECT this_.Id as y0_,

ca1_.Id as y1_,
this_.Name as y2_,
ca1_.IdAddressType as y3_,
ca1_.Street as y4_,
ca1_.Number as y5_, 
ca1_.ZipCode as y6_, 
ca1_.City as y7_, 
ca1_.Country as y8_, 
ca1_.Email as y9_, 
ca1_.Fax as y10_, 
ca1_.PhoneNumber as y11_, 
ca1_.CellNumber as y12_, 
ca1_.Url as y13_, 
@p0 as y14_ 

FROM CON_Company this_ inner join CON_CompanyAddress ca1_ on this_.Id=ca1_.IdCompany 
inner join CON_CompanyAddrTag tagalias2_ on ca1_.Id=tagalias2_.IdCompanyAddr

WHERE ca1_.Main = @p1 and this_.Status = @p2 and tagalias2_.Id = @p3',N'@p0 int,@p1 bit,@p2 int,@p3 int',@p0=3,@p1=1,@p2=0,@p3=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to join to `Tag` in order to do this:

```
if (_selectedTag != null)
{
    Tag tagAlias = null;

    company
        .JoinAlias(() => ca.Tags, () => tagAlias)
        .Where(() => tagAlias.Id == _selectedTag.Id)
}
```

(Assuming you want `Tag`s compared by `Id`)

The thing to remember about QueryOver/Criteria is that it's ultimately going to be turned into SQL. calling `ca.Tags.Select(...)` doesn't make sense from inside of a SQL query since there's an implied `JOIN` there to `Tag`.

Also, you're mixing QueryOver and Criteria syntax which is kind of confusing. I'd rework things a bit:

```
Company companyAlias = null;

var company = Session.QueryOver<Company>(() => companyAlias)
    .JoinAlias(c => c.Addresses, () => ca)
    .Where(() => ca.Main)
    .Where(c => c.Status == ContactStatus.Approved)
    .Select(
        Projections.Property(() => companyAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => sri.TopId),
        Projections.Property(() => ca.Id).WithAlias(() => sri.Id),
        Projections.Property(() => companyAlias.Name).WithAlias(() => sri.Name),
        Projections.Property(() => ca.Address).WithAlias(() => sri.Address),
        Projections.Property(() => ca.ContactData).WithAlias(() => sri.ContactData),
        Projections.Constant(ContactClassType.Company).WithAlias(() => sri.Type)
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't get the error anymore but the result doesn't seem right. A company can have more than 1 tag and I need only the companies which have the _selectedTag (int id) in their tag list.

Comment: @NanouPonette: Do you have a profiling tool you're using? If so, could you take a look at the SQL that's generated and see if that's what you expect?

Comment: Yes. It's not what I expect. I need to compare it with a list, not with 1 id.

Comment: You're trying to see if `_selectedTag` is in each `CompanyAddress` row you're evaluating right? To do that you have to join to `CompanyAddrTag` and see if `_selectedTag` matches any of the `CompanyAddrTag`s in the list. Are you sure the result is wrong?

Comment: Yes thats correct Andrew. But I don't know the exact code how to do this. How can I compare all items in CompanyAddrTag with the _selectedTag?

Comment: @NanouPonette: That's what the join is designed to do. Is the query returning too many or too few rows?